# Disk full after broken installation of KDE desktop and now cannot remove/uninstall anything

Tags: ubuntu, apt, kde, uninstall, delete

I wanted to install `Plasma 5.12` on my **Ubuntu 16.04.03** system. So I ran the following lines in Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt update && sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

However, in the middle of the installation I got an error that I did not manage to note down. Then I executed `df -h /`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       9.5G  9.0G   81M 100% /
```

Then I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge kubuntu-*
sudo apt-get remove --purge kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

For all of the above I received the same error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts 
 (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

Of course, `apt-get -f install` does not work either and gives me the following error:

```
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**QUESTION**:

How can I solve this issue? What can I do free up some space on my system and force uninstall `kubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove -f` did the job!

Comment: Second finding: `aptitude` is absolutely gold in these situations.